# Python: how do I save a file in a different directory?

Tags: python, filesystems

So right now - my Python program (in a UNIX environment) can save files.

```
fig.savefig('forcing' + str(forcing) + 'damping' + str(damping) + 'omega' + str(omega) + 'set2.png')
```

How could I save it in a new directory without switching directories? I would want to save the files in a directory like Pics2/forcing3damping3omega3set2.png.

Comment: Maybe see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31435921/difference-between-and

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By using a full or relative path. You are specifying just a filename, with no path, and that means that it'll be saved in the current directory.

To save the file in the `Pics2` directory, relative from the current directory, use:

```
fig.savefig('Pics2/forcing' + str(forcing) + 'damping' + str(damping) + 'omega' + str(omega) + 'set2.png')
```

or better still, construct the path with `os.path.join()` and string formatting:

```
fig.savefig(os.path.join(('Pics2', 'forcing{0}damping{1}omega{2}set2.png'.format(forcing, damping, omega)))
```

Best is to use an absolute path:

```
path = '/Some/path/to/Pics2'
filename = 'forcing{0}damping{1}omega{2}set2.png'.format(forcing, damping, omega)
filename = os.path.join(path, filename)
fig.savefig(filename)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can join your filename with a full path so that it saves in a specific location instead of the current directory:

```
import os

filename = "name.png"
path = "/path/to/save/location"
fullpath = os.path.join(path, filename)
```

Using `os.path.join` will properly handle the separators, in a platform independent way.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are working with `pylab` (`matplotlib`).

You can use a full path as the `fname` argument of `savefig(fname, ...)`, which can be either an absolute path like `/path/to/your/fig.png` or a relative one like `relative/path/to/fig.png`. You should make sure that the directory for saving the file already exists. If not use `os.makedirs` to create it first:

```py
import os

... # create the fig

dir = 'path/to/Pics2'
if not os.path.isdir(dir): os.makedirs(dir)
fname = 'forcing' + str(forcing) + 'damping' + str(damping) + 'omega' + str(omega) + 'set2.png'
fig.savefig(os.path.join(dir, fname))
```