# Difference between ./ and ~/

Tags: filepath, tilde

When creating filepaths and URLs, I noticed that many times the path starts with `./` or `~/`.

What is the difference between filepaths that start with `./` and `~/`?

What do each of them mean?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`./` means "starting from the current directory".  `.` refers to the current working directory, so something like `./foo.bar` would be looking for a file called `foo.bar` in the current directory.  (As a side note, `..` means refers to the parent directory of the current directory.  So `../foo.bar` would be looking for that file one directory above.)

`~/` means "starting from the home directory".  This could have different meanings in different scenarios.  For example, in a Unix environment `~/foo.bar` would be looking for a file called `foo.bar` in your home directory, something like `/home/totzam/foo.bar`.  In many web applications, `~/foo.bar` would be looking for a file called `foo.bar` in the web application root, something like `/var/http/mywebapp/foo.bar`.

Answer (score 36):

For the sake of completeness ...

- Just `path` is a file or directory named `path` in the current directory.
- `./path` is a file or directory named `path` in the current directory, with the directory spelled out. The dot directory `.` represents the current directory, and `path` is the name of the file or directory within this directory.
- `~/path` is a shorthand for `$HOME/path` where `$HOME` is a variable which refers to your home directory. Typically your home directory will be somewhere like `/home/you` or `/Users/you` where `you` is your account name. (The command `echo "$HOME"` will display your home directory.) The expanded value is an absolute path (unless you have messed up the value of `$HOME` thoroughly), as indicated by the initial slash.
- `/path` is an absolute path which refers to a file or directory named `path` which is in the *root* directory `/`. Every file on Unix is ultimately somewhere in the directory tree which starts with the root directory.

A file name which begins with `$` includes the value of a shell variable in its name (like for example `$HOME` above); you have to know the value of that variable to determine whether it ends up containing a relative or an absolute path. Similarly, `~` at the beginning of a file name gets replaced ("expanded") by the shell to a different string, as outlined above.
(Technically, it's possible for a file name to begin with a literal dollar sign or tilde, too; you would then have to quote or backslash-escape that character to avoid having the shell expand it to something else. This is rather inconvenient, so these file names tend to be rare in practice.)

In the following exposition, we refer to the result of any such replacements, and ignore the complication of possible quoting.

Every file name which begins with `/` is an **absolute** path (aka *full path)* which explains how to reach a particular node starting from the root directory.  For example, `/var/tmp/you/reminder.txt` refers to a file or directory `reminder.txt` (probably a file, judging from the name; but Unix doesn't care what you call your files or directories) which is in the directory `you` which is in the directory `tmp` which is in the directory `var` which is in the root directory.

Every file name which doesn't begin with `/` is a **relative** path which indicates how to reach a particular file or directory starting from the current directory. The special directory `..` is the parent directory (that is, the directory which contains this directory) and the special directory `.` is the current directory.  So `path/there` refers to the file or directory `there` inside the directory `path` in the current directory; and (hover the mouse over the gray area to display the spoiler)

> `there/.././and/back/..` is a (wicked complicated) way to refer to the directory `and` in the current directory, where we traverse the `there` directory and then move back to the current directory; then stay in the current directory; then refer to the directory `back` inside the directory `and`, but then move back to the parent directory of that, ending up with `./and`.

In addition to `~/` for the current user's home directory, some shells and applications allow the notation `~them/` to refer to the home directory of the user account `them`. Also, some web server configurations allow each user to have a public web site in their directory `~/public_html` and the URL notation `http://server/~them/` would serve up the site of the user account `them` for outside visitors.

The **current directory** is a convenience which the shell provides so you don't have to type long paths all the time. You can, if you want to.

```
/bin/ls /home/you/Documents/unix-101/directories.txt
```

is a longwinded but perfectly valid way to say (assuming you are in your home directory),

```
ls Documents/unix-101/directories.txt
```

You could also say

```
cd Documents/unix-101
ls directories.txt
```

and until you `cd` again, all your commands will run in this directory.

See [What exactly is current working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591428/what-exactly-is-current-working-directory) for a longer exposition of this related concept.

A "directory" is sometimes called a "folder" by people who are not yet old enough to prefer the former.

---

Tangentially, don't confuse the directory name `.` with the Bourne shell command which comprises a single dot (also known by its Bash alias `source`). The command

```
. ./scriptname
```

runs the commands from the file `./scriptname` in the context of the current shell instance, as opposed to in a separate subshell (which is what just `./scriptname` does). In other words, this command line invokes the *dot command* on a file `scriptname` in the *dot directory.*

The Bourne shell (and derivatives like Bash, Zsh, etc) use single quotes to prevent variable expansion and wildcard expansion, and double quotes to permit variable expansion, but inhibit wildcard expansion in a string. The quoting rules on Windows are different, and generally use double quotes to keep whitespace-separated values as a single string (and `%` instead of `$` for variable substitutions).

Comment: I like your explanation of how `~/path` is shorthand for `$HOME/path`. That definitely would have made things clearer when I asked this question back when I was first starting to program, and I'm sure others will find the explanation helpful in the future. Thanks for this detailed response even 3+ years later!

Comment: Very good explanation.

As far as the tilde (~) character goes, it actually means to take everything between the ~ and the first / and treat that as a username.  If that space is empty,  like ~/ or if the user does not exist, then it defaults to the current user. 

This is something that could lead to troubles if a script is run as another user or root using sudo and a malicious string.

Comment: @Skeptycal Thanks, I was just thinking about adding a passage about `~user`. Done now.

Comment: This broadly applies to Windows and DOS and some other similar atrocities as well, with the difference that DOS etc has a number of file systems, each with a separate drive letter (and the separator was backslash `\ ` instead of forward slash `/`). Typically `C:\ ` was the root of the first hard drive (and `A:\ ` was the root of the first floppy drive) back in the 286 days, though there are variations.

Comment: ("The 286 days" refers to the days of the Intel 80286 CPU, which many young readers will probably never have heard about. This was the predecessor of the somewhat more familiar 80386, or "386", architecture.)

Answer (score 6):

`./` is the current directory

`~/` is the home directory of the current user

Answer (score 3):

`./` means that path is relative to your current position.

`~/` means that path is relative to your home directory.

Answer (score 2):

`.` represents current directory

`..` represents the parent directory

`~` represents the home directory for the current user. Home directory is also represented by `HOME` env variable. you can do `echo $HOME` on the shell to see it.

These are generally used to specify relative paths. The `/` in the end of each notation is a separator that you can use when using these notations together.

Ex:

```
$ cd ../.. # Go 2 directories backwards
$ cd ~ # Takes you to $HOME directory
$ cd . # Does nothing :) As it literally means go to the directory that you are already present in.
$ cd ~/dir1 $ go to `$HOME/dir1`
```

On Unix, in any directory if you do `ls -a` you would see that `.` and `..` will be mentioned (even for empty directory). Like mentioned, these have special meaning and are generated by default in Unix systems and are generally helpful to specify relative paths (i.e, path to a different directory relative to your current directory)

`cd` command is harmless. So, just play around by combining notations with `cd` command. You will eventually get a grip of them.

Answer (score 0):

I will explain a simple example of it. As developers mentioned:

- `./` is current directory.
- `~/` is the home directory of the current user.

How both of the file path expressions can help us? Suppose you want to execute a script (.sh) and you're in the same directory where file exists then you can simply do it `./filename.sh`

I mostly use `~/` to access my home directory files like `.bashrc` when I want to add any config in it. It's easier since the file path expression (for home directory) feels much easier and makes accessibility to the file from anywhere, without worrying about the path or changing the path.