# What is the difference between path starting with '/' and '~/'

Tags: html, .net, href, umbraco7, favicon

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31435921/217757), but that is answering something else.

Today, I got a strange (at least to me) problem. The problem is, that I have this code in my website...

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="~/img/TT_favicon_16px.png" />
```

The favicon was returned on almost all of the pages of the website, but not on one of the pages of the website.

I just imagined (out of nothing) to remove the tilde sign and it started working on all of the pages on the website.

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/img/TT_favicon_16px.png" />
```

This raised my curiosity and I wanted to understand what is the difference between the two...

Comment: Do you use any meta base tags in your HTML of the pages where the favicon doesn't work, and where it does work ?

Answer (score 1):

It is contextual.

Let's say the current page's URL is `http://example.com/foo/bar.html`.

Absolute path links, starting with a slash, like `/quux/grault.html`, will replace the entire path, leaving the server alone: `http://example.com/quux/grault.html`.

Relative path links, not starting with a slash, like `fred/baz.html`, will append to the last slash of the path: `http://example.com/foo/fred/baz.html`.

Where HTTP and its interpretation is concerned, your tilde is nothing special. It is not a full URL, and it does not start with a slash, therefore it is a relative path URL, and within our example you'd end up with this URL: `http://example.com/foo/~/img/TT_favicon_16px.png`. When you remove the tilde, it becomes an absolute path link, and you get `http://example.com/~/img/TT_favicon_16px.png`.

When you visit those two links, what gets served depends on your web server configuration. I've never tried a link like `http://example.com/~/...` or `http://example.com/foo/~/...`, but I doubt it would work - most web servers are not configured to respond with anything sensible on such a URL (and indeed on my computer I get a 404 Not Found). Why you got a response there is impossible to say without inspecting how your web server is configured.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but what I can't understand is the resolving of the tilde sign in the `<link>` tag. I know that .Net translates that to the root of the application, but with <link> tag, how does it translates or if it is Visual Studio or .Net itself that does some magic here ?

Comment: "When you remove the tilde, it becomes an absolute path link, and you get `http://example.com/~/img/TT_favicon_16px.png`."  ... Actually if he removes the tilde, he does not get a url with still a tilde in it. He simply gets `http://example.com/img/TT_favicon_16px.png`