# RuntimeError when reading wav file

Tags: python, runtime-error, readfile, system-error

I am following the https://github.com/mravanelli/SincNet library . I have followed the documentation as suggested. but I got the RuntimeError

I have changed the file access using `sudo chmod +x /home/sathiyakugan/Downloads/TIMIT/data/lisa/data/timit/raw/TIMIT` but it didn't solve the problem.

This is the syntax that I executed 
`python3 TIMIT_preparation.py /home/sathiyakugan/Downloads/TIMIT/data/lisa/data/timit/raw/TIMIT /home/sathiyakugan/Documents/FYP/out data_lists/TIMIT_all.scp`

and this is the error I received.

```
  File "TIMIT_preparation.py", line 56, in <module>
    [signal, fs] = sf.read(wav_file)
  File "/home/sathiyakugan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/soundfile.py", line 257, in read
    subtype, endian, format, closefd) as f:
  File "/home/sathiyakugan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/soundfile.py", line 627, in __init__
    self._file = self._open(file, mode_int, closefd)
  File "/home/sathiyakugan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/soundfile.py", line 1182, in _open
    "Error opening {0!r}: ".format(self.name))
  File "/home/sathiyakugan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/soundfile.py", line 1355, in _error_check
    raise RuntimeError(prefix + _ffi.string(err_str).decode('utf-8', 'replace'))
RuntimeError: Error opening '/home/sathiyakugan/Downloads/TIMIT/data/lisa/data/timit/raw/TIMIT/train/dr1/fvmh0/si1466.wav': System error.
```

Comment: Related: https://github.com/bastibe/SoundFile/issues/227 ?

Comment: double-check the path. It was a problem in my case as well

Answer (score 0):

double check the path if it has permission issues or a typo. SoundFile module opens file not relative to the current folder but needs absolute path to the file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you show some examples of what you mean?

Comment: @WilliamBakerMorrison Do you mean you don't understand "use absolute paths"? Try [Difference between `./` and `~/`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55342466/874188) (the title is about a more specific issue but I posted an answer which attempts to explain the broader picture).