# How to exec into Docker container with ENTRYPOINT in its Dockerfile

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile that looks like this:

```
FROM image

WORKDIR /App
ADD ./App/ /App
ENTRYPOINT [ "./App" ]
```

In the App direction I am mounting a golang binary and its config.yml.

The image builds and runs correctly. When I am not running the container detached I can see the app is running as well.

But when I run it detached:

```
docker run -d image
```

I cannot exec into container after:

```
docker exec -it container bin/bash
```

With an error message:

> OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:345: starting
>   container process caused "exec: \"bin/bash\": stat bin/bash: no such
>   file or directory": unknown

I can understand **it has to do with the entrypoint** I set, but i am not sure what alternative i could use.

Any ideas?

Comment: docker exec -it container bash or docker exec -it container /bin/bash

Comment: I use /bin/bash. Is it that different?

Comment: no you use bin/bash

Comment: Yes you are right.Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should to specify full path to the binary file(`/bin/bash` in your case) or just name of the binary file located somewhere in your container's PATH variable(`bash`)

Comment: It's not strictly necessary to specify a full path, but you need to specify the correct path. If your working directory is `/App`, the path `bin/bash` refers to `/App/bin/bash` which of course doesn't exist. But the correct relative path `../bin/bash` would also work. Maybe see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31435921/difference-between-and

Comment: Yes, you right, it's a third option - path that relevant to workdir location, I forgot about this one, thank you for your clarification