# sh: line 0: cd: PRET: No such file or directory error in Python

Tags: python

I was trying to write a script using Python which used an open source pen-testing tool called PRET which I got from Github. I am using PyCharm for this.

My code was:

```
import os
def test():
    os.system('cd PRET')
    os.system('python2 pret.py')
test()
```

while doing that, I encountered this error:

> sh: line 0: cd: PRET: No such file or directory
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'pret.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: 1) **never** use `os.system`. It's unsafe and there are better alternatives in the `subprocess` module. 2) `os.system` spawns a new shell for each call, which means your `cd PRET` is doing nothing useful

Comment: If `pret.py` is at all competently written, it does not care which directory you are in when you run it. If so, `cd there; python2 pret.py` is a needlessly complex way to say `python2 there/pret.py`

Comment: The first error message means you do not have a directory named `PRET` in the directory where you are attempting to run this. Probably you need to understand the concept of current working directory first. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55342466/874188 has an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

`os.system()` will not rememeber the change of directory when the first execution terminates hence why your solution is not working.

As suggested in the comments, you can just omit the `cd` command just execute `pret.py` using the absolute path:

```
import os

def test():
    os.system('python2 <absolute_path>/PRET/pret.py')

test()
```

Comment: Still shows the same error: sh: line 0: cd: PRET: No such file or directory
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'pret.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Does `/PRET/pret.py` exist in the same folder as the script you are running?

Comment: Start by doing an `os.system('ls')` or `os.system('pwd')` - My guess is that the directory you are executing `cd PRET` in is not the same directory as you think it is

Comment: nope. let me try git cloning it to that then.

Comment: No. Just use an absolute path to whereever the script exists - see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

The two `os.system()` commands are separate, so after you `cd` in the first, that has no effect in the second. Try this:

```
import os
def test():
    os.system('cd PRET; python2 pret.py')
test()
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort but it still shows the same error:

Comment: sh: line 0: cd: PRET: No such file or directory
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'pret.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory