# Start script from different file directory using QProcess.start()

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, python-3.6, qprocess

I have tried looking this up, but for some reason I cannot find anything about it. How do I run a script by giving the particular file directory in start()?

This works (when Test is in the same folder as the main script):

```
self.process.start("python3 Test.py")
```

This does NOT work:

```
self.process.start("python3 /my/path/Test.py")
```

Comment: Have you tried putting two period in front of "/me" like this: ```self.process.start("python3 ../my/path/Test.py")```

Comment: @burntchowmein Ok, I did that and it works now. Before, I was doing ~/Documents/my/path/Test.py ---- Does the ~ not work?

Comment: @RamboPenguin Is the problem "~"? your question does not indicate that

Comment: @RamboPenguin Great! I am going to copy my answer down below so people in the future will have an easier time finding it immediately. I am not too familiar with ~ but see if this answer helps you understand it better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31435921/difference-between-and

Comment: @eyllanesc sorry, will be more clear in the future. Didn't think ~ was the problem because I've used it before without any issues in subprocess.run()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
self.process.start("python3 ../my/path/Test.py") # added two periods before "/m"
```