# Im trying to read a log file which is written in text in my Python program but its returning an "No such file or directory"

Tags: python

Even though it in the same directory as the Python file it cannot be red

```
from datetime import datetime

infile = r"./system.log.txt"
logFile = []
def readLog():
        
    with open(infile) as f:
        f = f.readlines()

    for line in f:
        temp= line.split('\n')
        logFile.append(temp[0])


def show():

    for line in logFile:
        print(line)
```

Comment: This issue may occurs when you are running the .py file from a different directory.
Try to `cd` into the same .py file and the logs file directory and run the .py file using `python fileName.py`

Comment: you dont need the `./` i guess . just try  `with open('system.log.txt') as f`

Comment: The system doesn't care which directory your script is in; it cares what your current working directory is when you start the script. Maybe see also [Difference between `./` and `~/`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55342466/874188)

Comment: As an aside, if you read the lines with `readlines()` there is no way that any of the lines can contain an embedded line break.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you have this sructure
folder
|--sys.log.txt
|--main.py

`cd folder` then `python main.py`

```py
file='system.log.txt'
with open(file,'r') as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the **path of your file** against what gets printed from the code below.

```
import os
print(os.path.dirname(__file__) + "/system.log.txt")
```

Also **for loop** needs to be indented properly.

```
import os

infile = os.path.dirname(__file__) + "/system.log.txt"
logFile = []

def readLog():
    with open(infile) as f:
        f = f.readlines()

        for line in f:
            temp= line.split('\n')
            logFile.append(temp[0])
```