# What will be the correct regex to match master and release?

Tags: bash, shell

I have to use different keys based on the branch name. If the branch name starts with release/master need to use the prod keys. But this regex doesnot seem to work in this shell script.

```
echo copying firebase keys based on the branch name
branch=$(git branch | sed -n -e 's/^\* \(.*\)/\1/p')
mkdir firebase
chmod 777 firebase
release="^(master$|release\/\S+)"
if [[ $branch == $release ]];
then cp  $(pwd)/firebase_keys/prod/*  $(pwd)/firebase;
  echo "prod firebase keys used"
else cp  $(pwd)/firebase_keys/dev/*  $(pwd)/firebase;
  echo "dev firebase keys used"
fi
```

Comment: Try switching the operator from `==` to `=~`, any better results?

Comment: nope the same results on changing  to =~,

Comment: OK, may need to adjust the regex; please post an example value of `$branch`

Comment: Whatever you are hoping to accomplish, **`chmod 777` is *wrong* and *dangerous.*** You will want to revert to sane permissions ASAP (for your use case, probably `chmod 755` or perhaps `775`) and if you have had world writable system files on a public-facing system, at the very least investigate whether it could have been breached and used as a pivot point for breaking into your organization’s network.

Comment: @tripleee it is just build thing for building the app with the respective keys.

Comment: @Milag branch can be someting like this master-develop-sync

Comment: This is not the place and the time for a discussion; but you are not convincing me that this is necessary or that you know what you are doing. Maybe post a separate question if you need help sanitizing that; feed free to ping me here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `=~` operator for bash regexp

```
re='^(master|release)'
if [[ $branch =~ $re ]];
then cp  $(pwd)/firebase_keys/prod/*  $(pwd)/firebase;
  echo "prod firebase keys used"
else cp  $(pwd)/firebase_keys/dev/*  $(pwd)/firebase;
  echo "dev firebase keys used"
fi
```

Update

```
re='^(master|release)'
[[ $branch =~ $re ]] && dir=prod || dir=dev
echo "$dir firebase keys used"
cp firebase_keys/$dir/* firebase/
```

Testing

```
test=(
    'asd master dvsdfc'
    'asf release sdflk '
    'master asdcal asdlk'
    'release sdddsfdf'
    'asfsf sdsd master'
    'asfasf sdfsdfrelease'
)

re='^(master|release)'
for string in "${test[@]}"; {
    [[ $string =~ $re ]] && printf "$string\tprod\n" || printf "$string\tdev\n"
}
```

Output

```
asd master dvsdfc       dev
asf release sdflk       dev
master asdcal asdlk     prod
release sdddsfdf        prod
asfsf sdsd master       dev
asfasf sdfsdfrelease    dev
```

Without regex

```
branch=${branch//master*}
branch=${branch//release*}
[[ $branch ]] && dir=dev || dir=prod
echo $dir
```

Comment: but i have to match anything after master also, the use case is that the branch name should start with master or release.

Comment: `cp  $(pwd)/firebase_keys/prod/*  $(pwd)/firebase;` will fail if `pwd` returns spaces, newlines or tabs. It will take options if `pwd` returns names starting with dashes `-`. You have to protect variable expansion and terminate options like: `cp -- "$PWD/firebase_keys/prod/"*  "$PWD/firebase";`

Comment: The regex matches anything which starts with either of those words.

Comment: @tripleee doesnot seems to match everything that starts with master.

Comment: Why do you believe that?

Comment: @tripleee i ran the script and checked

Comment: @rohitwtbs be sure to run your script with bash and not some other shell interpreter. The regex comparison `=~` only works with bash.

Comment: what about this regex release="[release|master][A-Za-z0-9._%+-//]*"

Comment: Unclear what you ran exactly; it works for me. Demo: https://ideone.com/I22CaP

Answer (score 2):

Without using Bashisms:

```sh
if [ -n "$branch" ] && ! {
    [ "$branch" = "${branch#master}" ] &&
    [ "$branch" = "${branch#release}" ]
  }
then
  cp -- "$PWD/firebase_keys/prod/"* "$PWD/firebase"
  echo "prod firebase keys used"
else
  cp -- "$PWD/firebase_keys/dev/"* "$PWD/firebase"
  echo "dev firebase keys used"
fi
```

How it works:

`"${branch#master}"` removes the leading word `master` from the `branch` variable.

Lets say the branch is `masterpiece`:

- `"${branch#master}"` would remove the leading `master` from `masterpiece` → `piece`

the `[ "$branch" = "${branch#master}" ]` comparison would translates into `[ "masterpiece" = "piece" ]` which is false, so it confirms that `masterpiece` starts with `master`.

So:

- `[ -n "$branch" ]`: if the branch name is not empty
- `&& !`: AND NOT
- `{`: Open grouping for the NOT condition statements
- `[ "$branch" = "${branch#master}" ]`: the branch name does not start with `master`.
- `&&`: AND
- `[ "$branch" = "${branch#release}" ]`: the branch name does not start with `release`.
- `}`: close the statements group

Answer (score 1):

Your regex has a few issues. Firstly, Bash doesn't support Perl extensions like `\S`. Secondly, harmlessly but revealingly, you don't need to escape the slash, because the slash character has no special significance in regular expressions. (There are some languages like Awk which use slashes as separators *around* regexes; then you do have to escape them. But Bash is not one of those languages.)

Anyway, especially if you are not very comfortable with regex, I would refactor to use a `case` statement instead. The syntax will seem alien at first if you are not already familiar with it, but I think you will find that this is actually quite readable, maintainable, and versatile (as well as portable to basic `sh`).

```sh
case $(git branch | sed -n 's/^\* \(.*\)/\1/p') in
  master/* | release/* )
    env='prod';;
  * )
    env='dev';;
esac
cp  ./firebase_keys/"$env"/*  ./firebase
echo "$env firebase keys used"
```

Notice also how the current working directory is already the default for any relative paths; there is basically never a need to use `$(pwd)` - or, in Bash, the more economical built-in variable `$PWD` - unless you specifically need to force absolute paths. (Perhaps see also [Difference between `./` and `~/`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55342466/874188))