# Python: Open file - No such file or directory

Tags: python, file

I'm new in python and i'm strugling with some problem...
I'm trying to get absolute path for each files with extenction .cls or .js
and after that I'm trying to read them and check if some pattern existing in reading file
but i got error that

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> 'C:\\Users\\MyUser\\Desktop\\scripts\\TEST_FILE.cls'

with double slashs

```
import csv
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import xml.dom.minidom as PT
import traceback
import glob, os
import traceback
from pathlib import Path

CLASSES_EXT = '.cls'
JS_EXT = '.js'

CLASSES_PATH = "../src/classes/"
LWC_PATH = "../src/lwc/"

#Function to get list of specific files
#argument
#path - is path where we are looking for files
#extention - extention that we are looking for
def getAbsolutePathForFiles(path, extention):
    try:
        filesList = os.listdir(path)
        retVal = []
        for file in filesList:
            if(file.endswith(extention)):
                retVal.append(os.path.abspath(file))
    except Exception:
        traceback.print_exc()
    return retVal

# function to check if label is using somwhere
def checkIfFileContainsLabel(fileName, label):
    try:
        filePath = Path(fileName);
        print('CO TU ', filePath)
        openedFile = open(Path(fileName), 'r+', encoding='utf-8')
        #with open(filePath , 'r') as readFile:
        for line in readFile:
            if label in line:
                return True
        return False
    except Exception:
        traceback.print_exc()



#Get list of file in which we will be looking for labels
classesFileList = getAbsolutePathForFiles(CLASSES_PATH, CLASSES_EXT)
jsFileList = getAbsolutePathForFiles(LWC_PATH, JS_EXT)

for pathToFile in classesFileList:
    retVal = checkIfFileContainsLabel(pathToFile,"CPT_From")
    print('RETVALU ', retVal)
```

Comment: The double slashes are just Python's way to disambiguate them. It should be easy to verify that the actual string only contains individual backslashes as directory separators.

Comment: when i do print(fileName) in chekIfFileContainsLabel it show me string with one backsleshes

Comment: Exactly. See the duplicate.

Comment: so how can i easly fix it ?

Comment: If the computer says the file doesn't exist, believe it. Common beginner mistakes are misunderstanding which directory the file is actually in (try dragging the file to a console / terminal / cmd window to reveal its full path; maybe see also [Difference between `./` and `~/`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55342466/874188)) and simply mistyping the path.

Comment: Like the now deleted commenter, I also wonder why you think you need to convert the file names to absolute paths; but this has no bearing on (what appears to be) your actual question.