# “CSV file does not exist” for a filename in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, csv, jupyter-notebook, anaconda3

i have the following code.and i have the csv file located in the path but when i run the code it just says that the file dosent exist at all.i moved the code to diff locations and changed the path to the new one and i also changed the name of the file but it didnt worked.also i add ".csv" to the name of the file but no good came of it.
here is the code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv
filename = ("C:\\Users\\Z\\pima-indians-diabetes.data.csv")
df1 = pd.read_csv(filename)
print(df1.head())'''
```

The error says

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File C:\Users\Z\pima-indians-diabetes.data.csv does not exist: 'C:\\Users\\Z\\diabetes'
```

Comment: Can you please show us your file tree?

Comment: file exist in "C:\Users\Z"

Comment: If the computer says the file doesn't exist, it's usually correct. A common beginner error is looking in the wrong place. Perhaps see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31435921/difference-between-and

Comment: my mistake was that i thought that i should add .csv to both code and the file but i understand that ishd have added that only to code and it worked.tnx dudes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the `*.csv` file extension in your code. Replace

```
filename = ("C:\\Users\\Z\\diabetes")
```

with

```
filename = "C:\\Users\\Z\\diabetes.csv"
```

Comment: In the description, he said that he added the extension and it didn't work

Comment: Yes, but he has parenthesis around the filepath. They need to go.

Comment: They are harmless as such.

Comment: see i did add .csv but it is in vain

Comment: yes finally it did worked tanks alot.i used to change the name of the file too and this time i didnt add .csv to the file but i just added to the code and it did worked,

Answer (score 0):

Few steps to check whether the file indeed exists:

- Open a Command Prompt (Click **Start** and type **cmd**)
- Type this command **dir C:\Users\Z\pima-indians-diabetes.***

  - This will clearly show if the file in question really exists.
  - It might not be there at all.
  - Or it might be named **C:\Users\Z\diabetes.csv.csv**.
  - Latter can happen when saving a file with **Save As** and typing **my-file.csv** for the file name, unaware that the application being used also adds the extension **.csv**, so now there are two of those.
- Here is the expected command output for an existing file with correct name:

```
C:\Users\Z>dir C:\Users\Z\pima-indians-diabetes.*
         983 pima-indians-diabetes.data.csv
               1 File(s)            983 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  220,040,663,040 bytes free
```

Comment: tnx alot dear reverent Doron. yes as u also mentioned my problem was the false name  as it was named C:\Users\Z\diabetes.csv.csv

Answer (score -1):

remove '.' from your filename. I think it is effecting your file format