# File not found error (Bash operator) : Apache airflow running on Docker

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, airflow

I am trying to run `bash` scripts using `Apache Airflow` on `Docker`

this is the bash script i am running,

```
#!/bin/bash

rootdir=/home/anti/Documents/logistics/ariflowtest

crondir="$rootdir/cron/$(date "+%Y%m%d/%H")"

mkdir -p "$crondir"
/usr/bin/python3 "$rootdir/her.py" >> "$crondir/cron.log" 2>&1
```

when i run the `Airflow DAG`, it shows this `error`

```
Running command: ./aus.sh 
[2020-11-12 08:15:14,821] {{bash_operator.py:122}} INFO - Output:
[2020-11-12 08:15:14,823] {{bash_operator.py:126}} INFO - /tmp/airflowtmp_856j2oz/task_ausg7zzejtp: line 1: ./aus.sh: No such file or directory
```

i tried passing relative path of the script , but it did not work

this is my dag code :

```
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator

import os
args={
    'owner' : 'anti',
    'start_date':days_ago(1)
}

dag = DAG(dag_id='sn_logistics2',default_args=args,schedule_interval='*/5 * * * *')
create_command_dpd = "./home/anti/Documents/logistics/ariflowtest/dpd.sh "
create_command_aus = "./home/anti/Documents/logistics/ariflowtest/aus.sh "

with dag:
    dummy_operator = DummyOperator(task_id='mothertrigger',retries=3)
    task_dpd=BashOperator(
        task_id='task_dpd',
        bash_command="/dpd.sh ",
        #bash_command = create_command_dpd,
        xcom_push=True,
        dag=dag
        
    )
    
    task_aus=BashOperator(
        task_id='task_aus',
        bash_command="/aus.sh ",
        #bash_command = create_command_aus,
        xcom_push=True,
        dag=dag
        
    )


dummy_operator >> task_dpd
dummy_operator >> task_aus
```

i checked if my dag folder is mount or not :

```
sudo docker inspect -f '{{ .Mounts }}' 1e6c9974a9f3
```

output

```
[{bind  /home/anti/Documents/dags /usr/local/airflow/dags  rw true rprivate}]
```

script files that i'm trying to run and docker compose file are at two different locations

script files are in :

```
/home/anti/Documents/logistics/ariflowtest
```

docker-compose is in :

```
/home/anti/Documents
```

and i made sure the folder is mounted correctly in the `docker-compose` file

```
version: '3.7'
services:
    postgres:
        image: postgres:9.6
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=airflow
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=airflow
            - POSTGRES_DB=airflow
        logging:
            options:
                max-size: 10m
                max-file: "3"

    webserver:
        image: puckel/docker-airflow:1.10.9
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - postgres
        environment:
            - LOAD_EX=y
            - EXECUTOR=Local
        logging:
            options:
                max-size: 10m
                max-file: "3"
        volumes:
            - ./dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags
            - ./scripts:/usr/local/airflow/scripts
            # - ./plugins:/usr/local/airflow/plugins
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
        command: webserver
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD-SHELL", "[ -f /usr/local/airflow/airflow-webserver.pid ]"]
            interval: 30s
            timeout: 30s
            retries: 3
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the scripts `aus.sh` and `dpd.sh` are not in the docker container. You can solve this by mapping these files as well. e.g.

```yaml
        volumes:
            - ./dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags
            - ./scripts:/usr/local/airflow/scripts
            - /home/anti/Documents/logistics/ariflowtest:/scripts
            # - ./plugins:/usr/local/airflow/plugins
```

In the dag code you'll have to change `bash_command="/aus.sh "` to `bash_command="/scripts/aus.sh "`. Same goes for `dpd.sh`.

Comment: file location is `/home/anti/Documents/logistics/ariflowtest` . Do i need to copy the file into the location you gave in your answer `/usr/local/airflow/scripts`?

Comment: I thought the script were in the mounted folder. Generally speaking if you want to use something inside a container you must either have it in the image or map it via docker-compose.yml (or using the right docker parameter)

Comment: The beef here is that it's definitely not in `.` as per the error message; so you have to correctly specify where it is.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `./home/anti/Documents/logistics/ariflowtest/aus.sh` where you almost certainly mean `/home/anti/Documents/logistics/ariflowtest/aus.sh` without a dot in front.

In brief, you are looking for a directory named `home` in the current directory, and inside that `anti`, and inside that `Documents`; where presumably the real location is inside `home` in the root directory.

Perhaps see also [Difference between ./ and ~/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31435921/difference-between-and)

Comment: the problem is mostly that the file is not "mapped" in the docker container. The path you're referring to is assigned to a variable never used.