# Robot Framework: does not accept relative path to json file

Tags: robotframework

```
*** Keywords ***

Test Data From JSON
    ${json} =    get file    C:/development/robot-scripts/TestProj/JsonFiles/TestData.json  ->[Absolute path works fine]
    
    ${json} =    get file    ${CURDIR}/TestData.json  ->[${CURDIR}: shows error variable definition not found]

    ${object} =    evaluate    json.loads('''${json}''')    json
    log    Hello, my name is ${object["un"]} ${object["pwd"]}    WARN
```

Here Absolute path to json file works fine. but i am not able to parse json data with relative path. Please help.

Comment: The simple relative path `TestData.json` refers to a file in the current working directory. Perhaps see also [Difference between `./` and `~/`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55342466/874188)

Comment: If you add `Log To Console     CURDIR: ${CURDIR}`, maybe you can see why the "relative" doesn't work ..

Comment: Thanks guys   Difference between ./ and ~/ – tripleee   is a ust read. It resolved my issue.