# How to have "make clean" ignore folders when deleting

Tags: unix, makefile

I was given a Makefile for an assignment that gives me a make clean
command. With the way the repository is set up, it deletes everything in the /bin and /out folders, except for a file called .gitignore. This is what the command looks like:

```
clean:
    find out/ ! -name .gitignore -type f -delete && \
    find bin/ ! -name .gitignore -type f -delete
```

Now that I'm doing my project, I need to store things in a folder called /bin/fonts and /bin/word_lists. I'm trying to modify the command so that it ignores these two files. The only problem is, I don't know what language these commands are written in, so I don't even know where to start looking at the syntax. Could somebody point me in the right direction? I tried something like this:

```
clean:
    find out/ ! -name .gitignore -type f -delete && \
    find bin/ ! -name .gitignore ! -name fonts/FreeSans.ttf -type f -delete
```

But it still deletes everything in fonts, and even if it did work the way I wanted, that doesn't really solve the problem of saving every single font in the folder.

I also tried this:

```
clean:
    find out/ ! -name .gitignore -type f -delete && \
    find ./bin -mindepth 1 ! -name .gitignore ! -regex '^./fonts/\(/.*\)?' ! -regex '^./word_lists/\(/.*\)?' -delete
```

following this post, but it instead deleted everything INCLUDING the folders bin/fonts as well as bin/word_lists.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Make recipes are written in POSIX shell syntax.  However, a shell script is fundamentally a way to run other programs.  In this case the program being run is `find`.  So you should look up the documentation for the `find` program, either on the internet (try something like `unix find`) or on your system (run `man find`).

Comment: Personally I strongly recommend you do _NOT_ put stuff you want to keep as subdirectories of `bin`.  Why not put them somewhere else?  That would make your life a lot simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-name` does not examine the full file path, it only matches against the file name (so `-name FreeSans.ttf` would match, but match this file name in any directory).

The predicate you are looking for is called `-path` but then you need to specify a pattern for the entire path.

```
clean:
    find out/ bin/ ! -name .gitignore ! -path 'bin/fonts/*
 ! -path 'bin/word_lists/*' -type f -delete
```

(Notice also how I condensed the `find` to traverse two directories at the same time. I assume you mean `bin` not `/bin`; perhaps see also [Difference between `./` and `~/`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31435921/difference-between-and/55342466))