# "No such file or directory" error when trying to load a .plist file

Tags: python, macos, terminal, plist, launchd

**Hi there:**

I am trying to load the following .plist file from my LaunchDaemons directory under my 'Library'. I want to execute my [executable file] every Sunday at 11:59PM.

When I type the following into terminal:

```
 launchctl load ~/Library/[username]/local.emailfriend.plist
```

It gives me the error of 'no such file or directory.'

Hardware: macbook pro
Executable file: a .py file that I converted to an executable file using pyinstaller --onefile [filename.py]

**My .plist file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>local.emailfriend</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>/Users/[myusername]/Documents/[executablefilename]</string>
        </array>
        <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>11</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>59</integer>
            <key>Weekday</key>
            <integer>7</integer>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

please note that my plist file has been saved to the LaunchDaemons folder under my Library.
Any help would be appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure it's `~/Library` and not `/Library`? There's two of them.

Comment: Thanks fsimonjetz for the comment - I tried it without the ~, but then got an error of invalid property list

Comment: That sounds like it solved the problem you asked about, and uncovered a new one.

Comment: Perhaps see also [Difference between `./` and `~/`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55342466/874188)

Comment: the / instead of ~/ worked, alongside me using putil (plutil?) terminal command to see what was wrong with my .plist file. Thanks!