# What does ../../ located within a file path means?

Tags: bash, shell

I saw some shell scripts that `cd` into some file path that starts with an alias and have /../../ in between, for example:
`$exampleroot/../../folder/subfolder/filename.zip`

i understand that /../ means root path but what does this /../../ refer to? does it mean capturing all misc sub folders in between regardless of the folders name?

Thanks

Comment: .. is the parent directory. ../.. is the grandparent.

Comment: Perhaps see also [Difference between `./` and `~/`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55342466/874188) which discusses the actual differences between absolute and relative paths, and thus the definition of the filesystem root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`..` means the parent directory, i.e. the one that contains `$exampleroot`. `../../` is therefore two levels up:

```
$ pwd
/tmp
$ mkdir -pv foo/bar
mkdir: created directory 'foo/bar'
$ cd foo/bar/
$ pwd
/tmp/foo/bar
$ cd ../..
$ pwd
/tmp
```

Comment: i understand that .. is parent directory but i am confused when it all put together. why do they still put the $exampleroot in front? do you mean with that they are referring to the folders 2 levels up within the $exampleroot path? for e.g. if $exampleroot is "/home/user/abc/def/ghi, then $exampleroot/../../ means /home/user/abc?

Comment: Well, `..` is the parent directory of `$exampleroot` of course. It's a relative path, not an absolute one. So after you edited that comment: yes. You can of course try this on the command line to check your understanding.

Comment: good point thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 2):

An example might help. Suppose `$exampleroot` is `/one/two/three/four` (and this is a directory). Then:

- `$exampleroot/..` is equivalent to `/one/two/three`
- `$exampleroot/../..` is `/one/two`
- `$exampleroot/../../folder` is `/one/two/folder`
- `$exampleroot/../../folder/subfolder/filename.zip` is `/one/two/folder/subfolder/filename.zip`

(Note: If `/one/two/three/four` is not a directory, then `/one/two/three/four/..` is not a valid path. And there are some weird exceptions if there's something like a symbolic link in the path, because going up a level in the directory hierarchy is not the same as un-following a symbolic link.)