# Makefile call to script issues

Tags: makefile

I have a script that calls to a linter and I want to implement it into my makefile and call to it with the command make lint.
A simple call to the script (linter) either with it's path or without does not work, eg:

```
.PHONY: lint 

lint:
         ./$(ROOT)/tools/Manage/linter
```

Even though that command works fine in the terminal. However I did get this command to work:

```
.PHONY: lint

lint:
        cd /$(ROOT)/tools/Manage/ ; ./linter
```

However I've been informed that cd'ing to run script is improper makefile
practice. Any help on cleaning this up would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `$(ROOT)` and `./$(ROOT)` are not the same.

Comment: "cd'int to run a script" is a perfectly reasonable practice, where it's needed.  There's no particular reason it should be needed here though.  As @Beta says, look very carefully at your paths and compare the one that works (on the command line) with the one that doesn't.  I'm sure you'll find they're different.

Comment: My answer to [Difference between `./` and `~/`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31435921/difference-between-and/55342466) also contains a brief discussion about the differences between `/path` and `./path`. [What exactly is current working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591428/what-exactly-is-current-working-directory) has some notes on why you might or might not avoid `cd`