# Python glob.glob can't find the file or returns empty list

Tags: python, glob

I am trying this code:

```
import glob
temp_path = glob.glob("/FileStorage/user/final/**/**/sample.json")[-1][5:]

sample = (spark.read.json(f"FileStorage:{temp_path}"))
```

However, when I run this command in databricks, the error message is:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I try to print the:
`glob.glob("/FileStorage/user/final/**/**/sample.json")` the result is an empty list.

Comment: If the result is empty then there's no -1th element. What were you trying to express with `** /**`?

Comment: Is the space after the double asterisk intentional, `final/** /**/`? Moreover, is the real file path exactly two directories deeper? If you want to have `glob` find the file even deeper, make sure to use [`recursive=True`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57644936/13106245).

Comment: hi, the space after double asterisk is not intentional. it's final/**/**/sample.json..also tried the recursive=True, same error message I got.

Comment: Please [edit] to provide information about what files exactly you have on your system which should match this pattern. The simplest explanation by far is often that no files match because the OP didn't understand how the file system works. Perhaps see also [Difference between `./` and `~/`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31435921/difference-between-and/55342466)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `"/FileStorage/user/final/** /**/sample.json"` is probably not the correct pathname for what you are trying to express. What you probably want is:

```py
glob.glob("/FileStorage/user/final/**/sample.json", recursive=True)
```

You need to remove the space from the pathname and add `recursive=True`.

Comment: hello, i tried this one however I got this error: **IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: dbfs:%5B%5D**  

Because it's from the 2nd line of my code w/c is: 

 sample = (spark.read.json(f"FileStorage:{temp_path}"))

Comment: Nothing in your question contains a relative path. You are doing something else wrong. `%5B%5S` decodes to `[]` so perhaps you are somehow trying to pass an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

```
import glob

path = r"C:User/FileStorage/user/final/*" # path to directory + '*'
for file in glob.iglob(path, recursive=True):
   print(file)
   #if you want to filter json format file
   if file.endswith(".json"):
       print(file)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the issue is with the '**'.

1. If you were trying to use a relative path then you should use only one '*' ("/FileStorage/user/final/*/*/sample.json").
2. If you wanted the search to be recursive/include hidden files, then you need to remove the space after the first '**' and set recursive=True or include_hidden=True (according to what you want) when calling glob.glob (for example: `glob.glob("/FileStorage/user/final/**/**/sample.json", include_hidden=True)` will return hidden files that are in this path)

> If recursive is true, the pattern “**” will match any files and zero
> or more directories, subdirectories and symbolic links to directories.
> If the pattern is followed by an os.sep or os.altsep then files will
> not match.
>
> If include_hidden is true, “**” pattern will match hidden directories.

see documentation here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html

Edit:
If this does not work, validate the path in your file system

Comment: hi thanks for this, i tried all your suggestions but same error 
IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: dbfs:%5B%5D


i just don;t understand it's okay last time then this error occurs.

Comment: maybe there are not supported file paths under final/** or final/**/** folders? do you have any files or folders with name that might be confused as part of the path and not part of the file name? something with ':' or similar chars? can you print the invalid path name?