# How to run sh file with path in unix

Tags: shell, unix

I am new to scripting and i am trying to run one sh script directly in my unix from root directly like below:

```
sh /tmp/myfolder/xyz.sh
```

but getting error like

> 'file doesn't exist'

I also use `./tmp/myfolder/xyz.sh` but it also failed.

Can anyone guide me for the same.

Comment: Does a file with that name exist at that path?

Comment: When the computer tells you a file doesn’t exist, it’s nearly always right. A typical beginner mistake is supplying the wrong directory name. If you are a Windows user, dragging the file to a CMD window will reveal its correct path; similar mechanisms are often available in other GUIs, too. In the meantime, we have no access to your computer, so we can't know whether the file exists under another name or not at all or etc. Perhaps see also [Difference between `./` and `~/`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55342466/874188)

Comment: The error message is, hopefully, not _**file**  does not exist_, but something like _sh : ..... xyz.sh does not exist_? Otherwise, the error is inside your xyz.sh script.

Comment: The file is present in the path when i try to run the file with teh below process it execute:
cd /tmp/myfolder/
sh xyz.sh
it executed Sucessfully but when i try sh command with the path and script name it fails

Answer (score -2):

#This command is for just checking what is inside this file.

~$ cat ./path/to/sh/file/e.sh

echo "Hello"

#To run bash file try this command.

~$ ./path/to/sh/file/e.sh

Hello