# How can I access a folder that is outside of the directory i'm currently inside of in python (I wanna use with open() to modify a .txt file.)

Tags: python, tkinter

I know my explanation may be quite giberish, but I made a picture to explain my problem to you.[Explanation pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xus03.png)

Let's take an example. I'm working inside the "save_files" directory, but I need a specific class or a function from the "Data" directory. How may I access that specific file? I'm planning on making this app public, so I can't just add "C:\Users\user\desktop" blah blah blah, because people have different user's and directories the desktop is in. How can I access that file?

(Also in this case i'm not talking about "from ... import ...", I'm trying to access the directory so I can modify the .txt file inside the other directory, meaning I'll need the path. `with open("*path needed*", "r+) as file:`, etc.)

Thank you for your time!

I tried to just give the path like normally but it didn't work.

Comment: Whoops sorry, I made a mistake. I'm not trying to get any functions or classes out of the data folder. I just need a PATH to the data folder.

Comment: Perhaps see also [Difference between `./` and `~/`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55342466/874188)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your directory structure, if you're working within the `save_files` directory and need to access a file in the `Data` directory, you can just use a relative path:

```py
import os

relative_path_to_file = os.path.join("..", "Data", "data.txt")
absolute_path_to_file = os.path.realpath(relative_path_to_file)

with open(absolute_path_to_file, "r+") as file:
    data = file.read()
```

Comment: Hey! I tried your suggestion, but it says "File not found", even tho i'm 100 percent sure I entered the right path. I copied the path and pasted, and modified it so it starts like "..\\Data\\data.txt", and still "FileNotFoundError". Please help me

Comment: Hi! I apologize for the initial solution not being cross-platform. I have updated the code to a version that should work on both Linux and Windows

Answer (score 1):

To have a robust access to your filepaths, I highly recommend you to use absolute paths.
For example, in your save_files/script.py, you can do:

```
import os.path
import sys

filepath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), "../Data/file.txt")
with open(filepath , "r") as file:
    data = file.read()
```

It may seem a bit wordy, but this way your script will run fine no matter where the current directory of your interpreter is. Because it will consider the "../Data/file.txt" path relatively to the place where your script is.
If you use the string path directly in the open function, it will consider the filepath relatively to your current directoy.

P.S. I have created a short helper method in my utils that I use in all of my projects when I manipulate filepaths to make the code more concise.