# Why is venv python directory not found?

Tags: python, python-venv, cd

I am following instructions to run code in my mac computer from this codebase: https://github.com/obaghirli/syn10-diffusion

In step 1, I entered the `syn10-diffusion` directory and ran following steps inside that directory.

In step 2, when I ran `python3.8 -m venv venv`, I got an error `zsh: command not found: python3.8`. Then, I ran `vim /usr/local/bin/`, and found python3 and python3.9 in this file. So, I ran `python3 -m venv venv`as python3.8 was not in the file. It gave no error. Thus, I continued with next commands.

Then, I ran all commands till step 4. To follow step 5, I need to be in the directory of `venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages` and create a file there. As I did not use python3.8 in step 2, I ran `venv/lib/python3/site-packages`. I am getting this error `cd: no such file or directory: venv/lib/python3/site-packages`. I tried running this command from both of the syn10-diffusion and home directory.

Any suggestions on what can I do?

I also tried running `cd venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages`. It gave a similar error `cd: no such file or directory: venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages`.

Comment: By your own exposition, the `venv` directory was created inside `syn10-diffusion`. You should easily be able to verify this yourself. The name `venv` is fairly generic, so it is not impossible that you have created other directories with the same name in other locations. If you are unfamiliar with how the file system is organized, perhaps read [Difference between `./` and `~/`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55342466/874188)

Comment: I love people doing "cargo cult programming" (google the phrase). The project you linked to simply expects that you are using a Python version not less than 3.8. Using Python version 3.9 should be fine. And the obvious substitutions in those directions should be, well, obvious.

Answer (score 1):

If your Python version is 3.9 then (I hope obviously) the directory name inside your virtual environment will be `venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages` as you could easily find out yourself with `ls` or using your shell's tab completion.

Depending on the project you are trying to implement, it may or may not work exactly as with Python 3.8. Both 3.8 and 3.9 are supported and stable versions at this point in time (though 3.8 reaches end of life in October of 2024. Of course this doesn't mean it will stop working then, just that it will no longer receive security updates etc).

What's available in `/usr/local/bin` is completely system-dependent (as in, out of the box, this directory will be empty) and we can't really know how Python 3.9 got installed on your system. On MacOS Sonoma, `/usr/bin/python3` is Python 3.9.6 so you will face similar issues if you try to use that instead of whatever someone (if not you yourself) installed somehow and forgot to document.

The name `/usr/local/bin/python3.9` vaguely suggests that your installation was created by Homebrew, but it will by no means be the only one which uses this convention, just the most popular one. Again, what exactly to expect depends on how exactly your local Python version was installed. If `/usr/local/bin/python3.9` is actually a symbolic link to `../Cellar/python@3.9/...` then that's a more definitive indication that it's a Homebrew installation.

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a virtual env using python3.9 and see if you can install all the requirements without any issues. If that doesnt work, you should install python3.8 in your Mac. For that you can do any of the following:

- brew install python@3.8
- Use pyenv to install python3.8

Comment: While this isn't incorrect, it should probably explain in more detail what each of these alternatives do. If the OP hasn't used Homebrew in the past, installing yet another Python version with `brew` will probably create more confusion down the line. I personally like `pyenv` a lot but it's probably also confusing without a slightly more detailed exposition. In very brief, it is a tool which allows you to maintain multiple Python installations in parallel, and easily switch between them.

Answer (score 0):

Before doing `cd venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages`, check which python interpreter is installed in your virtual env by doing a simple: `ls venv/lib`
and then replace python3.8 in `cd venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages` with the python version you have or try `cd venv/lib` then tab into the python directory and site-packages.